# CSS transform issue in safari browser

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

[This happens on ios devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oeq7K.png) When I run the following code for rotating card, it works fine on all device except safari browser. There is an issue with the icon and the card. I can see if I set transform style as 'preserve-3d' this issue occurs with the icon. But I want it to stay 2d. Why this issue occurs in safari browser, and how to resolve this issue. Please help.

```js
document.querySelector(".card").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("clicked");
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  transform-style: flat;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.back {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: purple;
}

.front {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.card.clicked .front {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.clicked .back {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0);
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: olive;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="front panel"></div>
  <div class="back panel"></div>
  <div class="icon">CLICK</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are missing the css-prefix for this css-property on safari
webkit-prefix

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Depends on OP's Safari version: https://caniuse.com/?search=backface-visibility

Comment: looks like you have a point,
but for some reason I have safari version 15.2 and it didn't work until I used the css-prefix